# Non-singular variety covered by pairwise disjoint singular subvarieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Can you cover a non-singular algebraic variety by pairwise disjoint singular closed subvarieties? Varieties are over an algebraically closed field of characteristic other than $2$ and $3$.

In characteristic $2$ and $3$ this is possible via quasi-elliptic surfaces as pointed out by abx.

Comment: How are you turning these subvarieties into a partition using axiom of choice?

Comment: In characteristic zero such a map does not exist, because the generic fiber is regular and therefore smooth. They do exist in characteristic $>0$: look for *quasi-elliptic surfaces*.

Comment: There is really nothing special about characteristic $2$ or $3$: if you allow fibres of higher arithmetic genus, there should exist smooth surfaces in all positve characteristics mapping to a curve with all (geometric) fibres singular.